# Binding the same data in GridView and DetailsView. Why am I not getting output for Details View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

### **1.** Grid View, I used this below code and am getting right output..

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

  {

        da = new OracleDataAdapter("select* from studentlogin where name='" + User2.Text + "'", con);

        da.Fill(ds, "studentlogin");

        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["studentlogin"];

        GridView1.DataBind();


    }
```

### **2.** I used the same code by altering ID for Details View..But am not getting output

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        da = new OracleDataAdapter("select* from studentlogin where name='" + User2.Text + "'", con);

        da.Fill(ds, "studentlogin");

        DetailsView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["studentlogin"];

        DetailsView1.DataBind();


    }
```

---

Am afraid this question may sound elementary..But your help will be appreciated..

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but your code is a SQL injection attack waiting to happen.

Comment: User2.Text: "bobby'; drop table studentlogin; --"

Comment: @TIm Medora..Thanks for the reply..I just checked "Sql injection" in wiki..Am aware my sql statements are poorly coded.But am currently in elementary level.Am just trying to learn.I will improve my coding soon.

Comment: Hi Thomas..I will try to learn using parametrized statements.But can u explain me little clear to solve my current problem.

Comment: @Thomas: Little Bobby Tables?  Love that kid!  :D  (+1 for timely xkcd reference)

Answer (score 0):

Can you write the the code for the Datalist in the .aspx file?
do you use Eval statement in the DataList?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.databinder.eval(v=vs.71).aspx